# return reference of static member variable c++

Tags: c++, reference, static

Is there any problem to return a reference of a static member variable?
(Reference to avoid copy cost)

Vector accepts 4 parameters(x,y,z,w);

.h

```
class MyClass
{
private:
   static const Vector POS;
}
```

.cpp

```
const Vector MyClass::POS(100,300,0,0);

const Vector& MyClass::GetVector()
{
 return POS;
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's fine. Same thing is done with some implementations of the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `POS` is declared `static` then its lifetime is the lifetime of the program, and so returning a reference to it is safe.

Comment: It is the lifetime of the class, not the program, isn't it?

Comment: @buffo Classes don't have lifetimes,. Objects do. and static member variables, but not classes.

Comment: Ok, I badly expressed myself. I meant: the lifetime of the instance of the class.

Comment: @buffo Right, which lasts until global objects are destroyed. So you might run into trouble if you try to use it from a destructor of a global object.

Comment: @buffo But if the member variable is declared `static`, then it doesn't need any instance.

Comment: @buffo: It's a `static` member variable. It is unattached to any instance.

Comment: For my clarified understatement: there will be a memory allocation for this static member variable, even if no instance will be created in a whole program lifetime?

Comment: @buffo Most likely the compiler will "allocate" memory for the static member variables together with all global variables, so in practice static member variables are nothing more than scoped global variables.